# Swap keys for unique values in a dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

```
a = {0: 'PtpMotion', 1: 'PtpMotion', 2: 'LinMotion', 3: 'LinMotion', 4: 'LinMotion', 5: 'LinMotion', 6: 'LinMotion', 7: 'LinMotion', 8: 'LinMotion', 9: 'PtpMotion', 10: 'LinMotion', 11: 'Wait'}
b = {}
for key, val in a.items():
    b[val] = key
print b
```

What I am trying to do is to swap value of the dictionary for key. But using this code, I lose some information of the dictionary, getting this output:

```
{'LinMotion': 10, 'PtpMotion': 9, 'Wait': 11}
```

Why does it happen?

Comment: ...so what result were you expecting, then?

Answer (score 4):

Each key can only occur once in a dictionary.  You could store a list of indices for each key:

```
import collections
b = collections.defaultdict(list)
for key, val in a.iteritems():
    b[val].append(key)
print b
# {'LinMotion': [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10], 'PtpMotion': [0, 1, 9], 'Wait': [11]}
```

Edit: As pointed out by ecik in the comments, you could also use a `defaultdict(set)` (and use `.add()` instead of `.append()` in the loop).

Comment: It would be better to store it as a set, not a list since it's clear that all values in it are unique.

Comment: @ecik: Thanks, included in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

When you say

```
b[val] = key
```

and val already exists,it overrides the setting, getting what you see. To get all values, you must map the original values to lists of keys, such as

```
from collections import defaultdict

b = defaultdict(list)
for key, val in a.items():
    b[val].append(key)
print b
```

When I do it (python 2.5.1), I get

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'LinMotion': [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10], 
                            'PtpMotion': [0, 1, 9], 
                            'Wait': [11]})
```

Answer (score 1):

Dictionary keys must be unique.  If you wanted to keep them all you'd have to make each value for `b[val]` a list and add the values to those lists.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want lists in the output dictionary:

```
from collections import defaultdict
a = {0: 'PtpMotion', 1: 'PtpMotion', 2: 'LinMotion', 3: 'LinMotion', 4: 'LinMotion', 5: 'LinMotion', 6: 'LinMotion', 7: 'LinMotion', 8: 'LinMotion', 9: 'PtpMotion', 10: 'LinMotion', 11: 'Wait'}
b = defaultdict(list)
for key, val in a.items():
    b[val].append(key)
print b
```

yields:

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'LinMotion': [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10], 'PtpMotion': [0, 1, 9], 'Wait': [11]})
```