# reversing dictionary in python

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python reverse / inverse a mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483666/python-reverse-inverse-a-mapping)
>   [Swap keys for unique values in a dictionary in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4413976/swap-keys-for-unique-values-in-a-dictionary-in-python)

Hello i want to understand how to reverse and compare dictionary values: for example :

if i have one dictionary with key:value format like this

```
     dicta =  [1:2, 9:8, 4:6, 3:2, 0:7, 1:34, 9:90, 1:8, 67:43, 54:23]
```

How do i reverse it such that values of dicta above become keys and keys become values like this:

```
     dictb =  [2:1, 8:9, 6:4, 2:3, 7:0, 34:1, 90:9, 8:1, 43:67, 23:54]
```

I am using python 2.5
pls help

Answer (score 10):

```
dictb = dict ( (v,k) for k, v in dicta.items() )
```

Comment: Why do I get `TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
` when running this line? My *dicta* is called `G.node` and comes from the `networkx` package.

Comment: I guess at least one of the values of  `dicta`  is a Python dictionary or is a nested data structure containing one. When constructing `dictb` you try to use an unhashable data structure as a key which is not allowed in Python.

Comment: So yes, my *dicta* is actually a dictionary of dictionaries. Does this mean that I cannot reverse it because of some (or all) of its elements being *unhashable*?

Comment: Yes. You have some unhashable values in your primary dictionary, and when you want to revert them those become keys.

Comment: What is your current use case ?

Comment: Well it's hard to explain in a few chars. I'd better ask to turn this into a chat. It is possible? The problem btw relates to the use of the `networkx` package. The dict of dicts I am referring to is the one that tells me for each node what are its connections.

Comment: So the node is the key and the dict of its connections is the value.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for dictionaries is the following:

```
dicta = {1:2, 9:8}
```

This will do the conversion:

```
dictb = {}
for k in dicta:
  dictb[dicta[k]] = k
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
dicatb = {}
for x,k in dicta.iteritems():
    dictab[k] = x
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Convert dict to a list of (key, value) pairs with [dict.items()](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items)
2. Reversing each element of list with [reversed()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#reversed) and [map()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map): `map(reversed, ... )`
3. Convert list of (key, value) pairs to dictionary: `dict( ... )`

   ```
   >>> d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
   >>> dict(map(reversed, d.items()))
   {1: 'a', 2: 'b'}
   ```